# What is the connection between density and distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory

X is a r.v. with distribution function_
$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x< 0\\ \frac{x}{2} & 0\leq x<1 \\\frac{1}{2} & 1\leq 
 x<2 \\ \frac{3}{4} & 2\leq x <3 \\ 1 & x\geq 3 \end{cases}$$

It has density 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} & 0\leq x <1 \\ \frac{1}{4} & x=2,3 \end{cases}$$

Im just wondering how they got the result of the density.
Im kinda confused on the relation between density and distribution function. There is a definition stating that if:
$$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f_x(u) d\mu(u) $$ Then $f_x$ is the density of X. Did they use this definition to get the density functions in those two cases, or is it something trivial that im missing?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? The definition you gave will give you the distribution when you know the density. The FTC will help you do the reverse.

Comment: Actually this is a mixture of a continuous random variable and a discrete random variable.  It has density $\frac12$ on $[0,1)$ and point probabilities (mass not density) of $\frac14$ at $2$ and $\frac14$ at $3$

Comment: @Henry So you calculate the density by taking the derivative of the distribution function or?

Comment: Note that the definition that you mention will always result in a continuous (cumulative) distribution function. The distribution function mentioned in your question is *not* continuous.

Comment: Based on the definition, you may ease the problem by viewing $F_X(x)$ as the area under $f(x)$ in $[0,x]$.

Comment: Where there is just a density, it is the derivative of the cumulative distribution function (ignoring sets of measure zero).  But there are cases where the cumulative distribution function does not have a derivative, such as here at $x=2$ and $x=3$

Comment: @Henry So what is the standard method to calculate it for those points?

Comment: @Mythomorphic Ok Im just a bit confused on how you derive the density function.

Comment: @drhab What is the intuition of density function? Im having trouble seeing the relation to the distribution function..

Comment: The distribution function determines the distribution. A relatively high density on some set corresponds with a relatively high probability that rv $X$ will end up in that set.

Comment: @drhab Okay that makes sense. But how do we determine the density when we are dealing with non continuity, how did they calculate those points to have the density 1/4 ?.

Comment: You measure the step change in the cumulative distribution function at that point

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the density given a random variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a graph of your two functions plus a third graph, the "pseudo" inverse of $F$.

[image: probabiliy density and distrubution function, with inverse]

Take a look at the top graph, the graph of the density function $f$.

Since the second graph, $F$ purports to be the integral of of $f$, imagine a vertical line moving to the right along the graph of $f$ begining at the $y$-axis.

The area under the graph of $f$ and to the left of the moving vertical line will increase at a constant rate from a value of 0 to a value of $\frac{1}{2}$ which is what we see happening in the graph of $F$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

When the moving vertical lines crosses the gap between $1$ and $2$ there is no increase in the area accumulated so far, so it remains fixed at a value of $\frac{1}{2}$ which, again, is what we see in the graph of $F$.

But when the moving line gets to $2$ the probability has an instantaneous increase of $\frac{1}{4}$. This can be a bit perplexing because we are using the idea of "area" but how can this increase the "area"? This is a perfectly legitimate question. But remember we are using the graph as a model of probability, and the probability does suddenly increase by an amount of $\frac{1}{4}$ so this fact must be represented in the graph of $F$: the graph of $F$ has a discontinuity at $x=2$ and instantaneously increases by $\frac{1}{4}$.

As the moving vertical line crosses the gap in $f$ on the interval from $2$ to $3$ there is no further increase, so the graph of $F$ remains constant at a value of $\frac{3}{4}$ on that interval.

When the moving vertical line on $f$ gets to $3$ there is a final increase in probability of $\frac{1}{4}$ and the graph of $F$ has another discontinuous increase of $\frac{1}{4}$ to a value of $1$, and there it remains.

I have added a third graph labeled $F^{-1}$ as a bonus.

Suppose one picks a uniform random variable $X\in[0,1]$ on this third graph. Then the random variable $Y=F^{-1}(X)$ will equal $2$ with a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$ and will equal $3$ with a probability $\frac{1}{4}$, otherwise it will be uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$ with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$.

So the random variable $Y$ has probability density function $f$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment, I think John has posted what the OP actually wants. There is a usual way to make sense of $f$ as a density.
If you want to be pedantic, $f$ is the "density" (Radon-Nikodym derivative) of the distribution *with respect to the measure $\mu=\nu_{[0,1]}+\delta_2+\delta_3$*, where:

- $\nu_{[0,1]}$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$
- $\delta_a$ is a discrete measure concentrated at $a$ where for some Borel set $S$, then $\delta_a(S)=1$ if $a\in S$ and $\delta_a(S)=0$ otherwise.

For this $\mu$ the integral characterization $P(S)=\int_Sf(u)d\mu(u)$ works again. 
I would not unconditionally call the $f$ they got a 'density' without also specifying that it is against the above $\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

Densities are linked with underlying measures.

Is the function $f$ mentioned in your question a density of the distribution function mentioned in your question?

Yes, but this only if the underlying measure is a very peculiar one.

An example (there are more) is the measure $$\mu:=\lambda+\delta_2+\delta_3\tag1$$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and for constant $c\in\mathbb R$ measure $\delta_c$ is prescribed by $A\mapsto1_A(c)$.

Then $$\begin{aligned}\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)\mu(du) & =\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)(\lambda+\delta_{2}+\delta_{3})(du)\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)\lambda(du)+\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)\delta_{2}(du)+\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)\delta_{3}(du)\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)\lambda(du)+f(2)1_{(-\infty,x]}(2)+f(3)1_{(-\infty,x]}(3)\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)\lambda(du)+\frac{1}{4}1_{(-\infty,x]}(2)+\frac{1}{4}1_{(-\infty,x]}(3)\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{x}1_{\left[0.1\right)}\left(u\right)+1_{\left\{ 2,3\right\} }\left(u\right)\lambda(du)+\frac{1}{4}1_{(-\infty,x]}(2)+\frac{1}{4}1_{(-\infty,x]}(3)\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{x}1_{\left[0.1\right)}\left(u\right)\lambda(du)+\frac{1}{4}1_{(-\infty,x]}(2)+\frac{1}{4}1_{(-\infty,x]}(3)\\
 & =F_{X}\left(x\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

If some function gets the predicate of density of distribution then - unless stated otherwise - it will be a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Using peculiar measures like $(1)$ in most cases makes no sense and causes confusion. You are the living proof of that.